# Global.asax Events Fire in Unexpected order Application_End before Application_Start

Tags: asp.net, events, rest, nlog

I have recently added NLog (http://nlog.codeplex.com/) logging to an Asp.Net ReSTful webservice.

The logging is now working correctly and as expected, but the result is unexpected.  The order of the events which are firing in Global.asax isn't proving to be a useful output in the logs.

The events are as follows:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    logger.Info("Application Started");
}

void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //  Code that runs on application shutdown
    logger.Info("Application Ended");
}

void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    logger.Error("Unhandled Application Error");
}

void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started
    logger.Info("Session Started");
}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when a session ends. 
    // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
    // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
    // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.
    logger.Info("Session Ended");
}
```

The log output isn't what you would expect. This is a start then stop.

```
2013-01-03 14:54:25.2106|INFO|PoppyService.Global|Application Ended
2013-01-03 14:54:25.8166|INFO|PoppyService.Global|Application Started
2013-01-03 14:54:27.3610|INFO|PoppyService.Configuration|Configuration Registration
2013-01-03 14:54:29.9170|INFO|PoppyService.Global|Session Started
2013-01-03 14:54:36.7722|INFO|PoppyService.Global|Application Started
2013-01-03 14:54:36.9750|INFO|PoppyService.Configuration|Configuration Registration
```

The events are triggering in unusual orders and at the wrong times.

p.s. Ignore 'Configuration Registration'

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to launch the service at present, and the Servers setting in Properties -> Web is set to 'Use Local IIS Web server' rather than the VSDS.

Breakpoints placed in the events don't STOP the execution except for Session_Start, but I'm guessing this is because the events happen before the debugger kicks in or again might be because of using IIS server?